# query clearInterval when variable is "x"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

I have made a function that is controlling a row in a my database for a certain number with AJAX.
Im calling the function with a click function and putting the function in a setInterval function to make the check 10 times a second.

In the beginning it will return 0, but at some point (usually within 5 seconds) it will return something els than 0, when it does i want to clearInterval.

But im not sure how to this?

This is my function:

```
function get_buzzer() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_buzzer.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        job: 'get'
    },
    success:function(s) {
        if(s['number'] == 0) {
            var player = false;
        } else {
            var player = true;
        }
    }, error:function(e) {
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        var buzzer = setInterval("get_buzzer()",100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //make buzzer a share variable
    var buzzer;
    $('#test').click(function () {
        buzzer = setInterval(get_buzzer, 100);
    });

    function get_buzzer() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_buzzer.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                job: 'get'
            },
            success: function (s) {
                if (s['number'] != 0) {
                    //if number is not 0 then clear the interval
                    clearInterval(buzzer)
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {}
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : declare global variable to store interval and call `window.clearInterval` in success call of ajax

```
var buzzer;

function get_buzzer() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_buzzer.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        job: 'get'
    },
    success:function(s) {
        if(s['number'] == 0) {
            var player = false;
        } else {
            var player = true;
            //clear interval 
            window.clearInterval(buzzer);
        }
    }, error:function(e) {
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        buzzer = setInterval("get_buzzer()",100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

inside success use: And make var buzzer Gloval var.

```
    clearInterval(buzzer);
```

[Refence](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the interval in the success handler of ajax call over a condition.

```
        success: function (s) {
            if (s['number'] != 0) {
                //if number is not 0 then clear the interval
                clearInterval(buzzer)
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {}
```